# Handle unknown properties with typed JSON.deserialize()

Tags: apex, json, rest, deserialize, parser

I am looking for an elegant and unhacky way to handle deserialization of a JSON into an Apex type where some of the properties are known and some are not.

Assumption: At least for now the unknown properties are flat primitives. So no Maps or List or nested structures.

So this JSON

```
{
    age: 34,
    name: 'James',

    xyz: 2323,
    abc: '2131'
}
```

should be parsed by calling

```
Person p = JSON.deserialize(json, Person.class);
```

where Person.cls looks like this:

```
public class Person {
    public Integer age;
    public String name;

    public Map<String, Object> properties;

    ...
}
```

**I know that [this can be done in other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253875/deserialize-json-with-known-and-unknown-fields), but I (until today) heard of no working solution in Apex.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was toying around with some ideas for this and ended up documenting my work in [this repo](https://github.com/adrian-cg/dynamic-json-apex).

tl;dr: Here's the [relevant Apex file](https://github.com/adrian-cg/dynamic-json-apex/blob/master/force-app/main/default/classes/DynamicJSON.cls) and some [usage examples](https://github.com/adrian-cg/dynamic-json-apex/blob/master/force-app/main/default/classes/DynamicJSONTest.cls).

Answer (score 3):

This was the closest solution I could come up with and its good enough:

```
public class Person {

    public final String knownProperty;

    private Map<String, Object> unknownProperties = new Map<String, Object>();

    public Object get(String propertyName) {
        return unknownProperties.get(propertyName);
    }

    public static Person newInstance(String jsonString) {
        Person result = (Person) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, Person.class);
        result.unknownProperties = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
        return result;
    }


    public static List<Person> newInstances(String jsonString) {
        List<Person> result = (List<Person>) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, List<Person>.class);

        Integer i = 0;

        for(Object properties : (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString)) {
            Person person = result.get(i);
            person.properties = (Map<String, Object>) properties;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Nifty! Can't think of another solution off hand